# Ms Access : "Unrecognized Database format"

Tags: microsoft-access, visual-basic, runtime-error

I have an VB6 project which use the database MS Access 2000. With some electricity problem i lost the database file from project, but with the help of some recovery based tools , i recover the data , but the problem is that when I try to open the project with recover MS Access database , the project generate the error. I think my MS Access file is corrupt. So How to repair the database file , so I recover my all data.

Comment: Restore from your regular backups.

Comment: sorry, i have no regular backup\

Comment: I would create a new blank database and try to import (copy) all the database objects from the database. If I can't import ALL the objects then just the tables. As I recall most recovery tools can only expect to recover a certain amount of the *data* from the database.